# Spark loading ORC files does not use exact schema from Hive Metastore causing type casting errors

Tags: apache-spark, hive, databricks, orc

I am trying to load some data from a Hive table where one of the columns is like this:

```
id - bigint
```

When I load the table into a dataframe and do a printSchema, I see that Spark agrees with the Hive Metastore that id is of type long.  However, when I try to do anything with the table, I get this error:

```
SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 14.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 14.0 (TID 218, 10.139.64.41, executor 1): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcDeserializer$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$orc$OrcDeserializer$$newWriter$6.apply(OrcDeserializer.scala:94)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcDeserializer$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$orc$OrcDeserializer$$newWriter$6.apply(OrcDeserializer.scala:93)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcDeserializer$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(OrcDeserializer.scala:51)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcDeserializer$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(OrcDeserializer.scala:51)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcDeserializer.deserialize(OrcDeserializer.scala:64)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReaderWithPartitionValues$2$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(OrcFileFormat.scala:234)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReaderWithPartitionValues$2$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(OrcFileFormat.scala:233)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anon$2.getNext(FileScanRDD.scala:283)
at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:401)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:249)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:640)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.UnsafeRowBatchUtils$.encodeUnsafeRows(UnsafeRowBatchUtils.scala:62)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$$anonfun$2.apply(Collector.scala:159)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$$anonfun$2.apply(Collector.scala:158)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:140)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:113)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$13.apply(Executor.scala:528)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1526)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:534)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

It seems that Spark reads the data, decides that an Integer is enough to hold the data, and then tries to reconcile with the Hive Metastore who expects a Long.  How do I go about solving this?

EDIT:

I have tried reading the data in two ways, although I suspect they are the same:

```
spark.sql("select * from databaseName.tableName")
spark.table("databaseName.tableName")
```

Answer (score 0):

The `bigint` is not a supported datatype as documented here - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-reference.html

You can use the `cast` function to convert bigint to long

```
val newDF = df.select($"cola", $"colb".cast("Long"))
```

Comment: That did not work and I still received the same error.  Also, should BigInt and Long be the same thing?  They are both 8 bytes -- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-NumericTypes

Comment: Can you update your question with how you are reading the table so that we can take a look at what is going on?

Comment: Done.  Made edit at the bottom of the original post.